# Rails on Ubuntu server 14.04, not loading application layout

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, erb

I just finished my app in my development laptop, and now I am trying to deploy to an ubuntu server. I installed everything and ran rails s to try the development environment there. It works, but it never loads the css or js, I precompiled them and double checked that they are in the public assets folder. 
The problem is that it never asks for them. For example, my application layout view it like the usual (just as an idea, not the actual code, but it is not needed to explain):

```
<html>
<head>
  ----rails calls to application.js and css 
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I load the login page, there is no css. I check the page source, and it only shows the <%= yield %> part, no html, body, or head tags, and of course no references to css or js. I login, and navigate the app correctly, but never is there any css or js files used.

Why is this happening? Nothing changed in the code, just a different machine. I've tried it in different machines, just copying the folder with all my code, and running bundle install then rails s, and it works great, in 3 different machines. Why doesn't it work on the ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it working. 
For whatever reason, rails lost the default value of what view to render in the application controller. 
I added the following line to the application controller and it worked:

```
layout "application.html.erb"
```

No idea why this is needed, since it is the default.